# Swift: Gesture recogniser isn't registering

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm not sure why, but my gesture recogniser for my controller does not seem to be registering, I'm using a `UITableViewController` and have carried out the following steps:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self   // This should be done already as it is a subclass
                                // of UITableViewController, just put this to debug...

    // Gesture Recognisers - never seems to register (action never called)
    let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
    swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down
    self.tableView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)
}
```

After registering the callback action for the gesture in `viewDidLoad()` I have the following method declared:

```
func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    // Can we unwrap safely?
    if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {

        switch swipeGesture.direction
        {
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down:
            break
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up:
            break
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left:
            break
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right:
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

I set breakpoints throughout the `respondToSwipeGesture()` func, but it appears that the method is never even called - what could be causing this? I run some data model population methods on a separate thread, but I don't believe that should conflict with the gesture recogniser being registered.

Comment: It sounds to me as if the `tableView` intercepts and consume the touches events before your swipe gestures. Probably you could prefer adding the gesture recogniser to your tableViewCells.

Comment: that makes complete sense, I'll give that a try

Comment: Anyway consider that from a user point of view, it might seem impractical to swipe down on a vertical scrolling container. With the gesture inside the cell, probably you should implement the gesture delegate anyway, in order to let the normal vertical scroll steel works.

Comment: What I actually want is to detect whether the user is scrolling up, to determine whether the new card should perform their animation (similar to how Google+ app works)

Comment: Consider that your controller can be the scroll view delegate of your `tableView`. Just setting the delegate of your tableView to your controller. Then you will receive the various scroll view events happening inside the `tableView`'s scrollView.

Comment: Could you provide an example of that? Would be happy to accept it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a simple example that just prints if your tableView is scrolling up or down:

```
var offsetY: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            if oldValue > offsetY {
                println("Going down!")
            } else {
                println("Going up!")
            }
        }
    }

    //MARK: Scroll View Delegate

    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        // Verify that the sander is your tableView
        // Not needed if the only scrollView is the tableView
        if scrollView === self.tableView {
            offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        }
    }


    //MARK: View Lifecycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        // You can do it in your storyboard
        tableView.delegate = self

    }
```

Once your ViewController is the tableView delegate it will receive also the `UIScrollViewDelegate` messages from the tableView's scrollView.
In the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol you will probably find what you are looking for. The example above can be used to keep another view *sticky* in a fixed position inside the tableView.